# Is generic list construction ignored if the instance already exists?

Tags: c#, resharper, generic-list, branch-prediction, object-construction

I've got this code:

```
if (null == _priceComplianceSummaryList)
{
    _priceComplianceSummaryList = new List<PriceComplianceSummary>();
}
```

Resharper flags it as an issue, suggesting, "Replace 'if' statement with respective branch" If I acquiesce, the code above changes to:

```
_priceComplianceSummaryList = new List<PriceComplianceSummary>();
```

Yet it seems R# is often more the belt-and-suspenders type of "cat," urging me to always check if something is null prior to referencing it. So is this ostensibly reckless behavior on its part really just a matter of efficiency? IOW, does "new List<>" only generate a new list if the istance variable (_priceComplianceSummaryList) is null, without having to explicitly check that?

Comment: "IOW, does `new List<>` only generate a new list if the istance variable is `null`, without having to explicitly check that?"
No, it does not.

Comment: The only reason I can see R# suggesting this is because it can determine that `_priceComplianceSummaryList` is *always* null when you make this check, e.g. you're in a constructor and there's no static initialization of the field, making the check redundant. There is nothing special about the `new` keyword when instantiating a `List<T>` - after the assignment `_priceComplianceSummaryList` will *not* be `null`, and whatever (if any) value it had before, be it `null` or not, it will no longer have.

Comment: Can you show the code where you define this variable? Also, what is the scope of the variable? Please show all the relevant code.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Now it's right there: var _priceComplianceSummaryList = new List<PriceComplianceSummary>();
So I guess there was no possibility of it being anything but null at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Replace 'if' statement with respective branch" R# suggestion means that there is no scenarios when your boolean expression returns `false`. For example,

```
void SomeMethod(bool firstParam)
{
    var secondParam = true;
    if (firstParam || secondParam)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This code will refactor by R# because `firstParam || secondParam` is always true.

Then, your 2 examples of code are not always equivalent, but in your scenario they are.